# Superfluous hat description for Philantropist

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The [Philantropist hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/philantropist) says:

> Award a bounty, to someone else, on the last day of hats

[image: philantropist hat with description]

While you can *place* a bounty on your own question, you [cannot *award* a bounty to yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/295232). Why does the Philantropist explicitly mention this? Less is more, so I think it should be

> Award a bounty on the last day of hats

or, to be more consistent with other date-based hats:

> Award a bounty on January 8th

(unless, as Wrzlprmft notes, this hat works in another way than the other date-based hats)

Comment: At least the extra line prevents wining afterwards.

Comment: +1 for **Award a bounty on January 9th**, -1 for dropping **to someone else**

Comment: Though would it be on 8th or 9th? On the [blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1), it says: "Starting today through the end of the day on 8 January 2017".

Answer (score 11):

Because redundancy (i.e. sometimes "more is better") in language is often necessary for clarification.

Every day new users join, they might not know what a *bounty* is, but they will know that they cannot award it to themselves.

Answer (score 9):

We used that wording because we're specifically making you award the bounty. You won't get the hat if the bounty is automatically awarded to a winning answer. You have to select a winner in order to get the hat.

Comment: But the addition *to someone else* doesn't make that any clearer, does it?

Comment: I don't know about that @Glorfindel. I've read it and I think it's clear.

Comment: Well, to me, it's definitely *clear*, it's just some extra ruse. To me, the current wording feels like `if (i > 2 && i != 0) {`. It's OK if you want to put a [status-declined] on this [feature-request]. I was only slightly irked by the current wording.

Comment: Ok, I keep it in mind for next year's bashing @Glorfindel. But I don't think we'll change it this time round.

Comment: You missed the point of the question. No big deal though. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The question asked why it said it, I answered that. It's ok if you don't like my answer though. :)

Comment: Wait, there's a bug in the answer...